# Egg wash substitute

Tags: egg-substitutes

Many bread and pastry recipes ask to egg wash the dough surface before baking to give the finished product a shine and firm texture. Is there a vegan substitute for egg wash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good alternative is a mixture of 1 part aquafaba, 1 part soy or almond milk and 1 part maple syrup. The maple syrup will caramelise while baking to give the brown shine and the aquafaba will help to add firmness.